# How to reference a file in the same folder in a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file

I am using the batch script below to import a certificate. Problem is I need to change directory first to use a tool but then the import command breaks because the file cannot be found. Is there a way in the -file parameter to specify that the file is in the same place as the script is being run?

```
CD c:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin
keytool -import -v -file ".\PrimeVisit" -keystore "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs"  -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

Comment: which batch file ?? where does it located ?

Comment: Should be quoted because there is a space:`CD "c:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin"`

Comment: I didn't know there was a `-import` command, only `-importcert`, `-importpassword` and `-importkeystore`; see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html).

Comment: Actually, when  Command Extensions are enabled, which is the default setting, the `CD` command does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it's okay to CD into a subdirectory name which contains a space without surrounding the name with doublequotes.

Answer (score 0):

Save the current directory before changing it with the CD command.

```
set BASE_DIR=%CD%
CD c:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin
keytool -import -v -file "%BASE_DIR%\PrimeVisit" -keystore "%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\trusted.certs"  -storepass changeit -noprompt
```